# UIAppearance for custom controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiappearance

I have a custom view controller, say `MyViewController`. It has a color property which should be changed using `UIAppearance` mechanism. I did what the documentation is telling to do - marked the property as `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`. The controller conforms to `UIAppearance` and `UIAppearanceContainer`. When I tried to run the app I got a crash:

```
'+[MyViewController appearance]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10d6724f8'
```

Why are the appearance methods not generated for my class? Is it because of being a view **controller** and not a view? If yes then does this mean that custom `UIAppearance` properties are only supported for `UIView`s?

**UPDATE:** posting some code example:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIAppearance, UIAppearanceContainer>

@property (nonatomic) UIColor *blurTintColor UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;

@end
```

...

```
// somewhere in theme setup codes which run when launching the app
MyViewController *cont = [MyViewController appearance];
cont.blurTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: Can you post some code for us to look at?